# Add space before asp.net label in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I want to add some space before asp.net Label.I can't do this in .aspx ,I want this to be done in c#.How can I add space?? please help me.my label is placed like this:

```
                    Label Test
```

I want this to come to centre

```
                                       Label Test
```

Comment: Do you mean `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: ya but how this be done in code behind??

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: actually this consists of 4 td inside a tr, Based on condition I have hidden 2 td, so only my label not getting aligned, So how can i solve this in c#

Comment: Table ? what about that `<td align="right" >` ? Show your code please , you may need column span property .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add spaces to your label text from c#, you can pre-append many HTML non-breaking spaces by using `&nbsp;` Example:

```
Label1.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + Label1.Text;
```

Comment: css is a far better solution imho.

Comment: Very bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the style `text-align: center` to its parent.

You can have a parent like:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align:center">
<label>text</label>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can give a width and block to the label itself:

```
<label style="display:inline-block; width:100%; text-align:center">text</label>
```

For code-behind you can add it to attributes:

```
YourLabel.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("text-align", "center")
```

Comment: <div id="wrap" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;"><label id="xx">text</label></div>

Comment: The one you have suggested for code behind will work when there is a textbox beside???

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the exact code snippet that you have? I mean aspx markup.

Answer (score 2):

## Try adding the Css Style or Css Class:-

`lblTest.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-left", "<value>");`

or

`lblTest.Attributes.Add("class","<className>");` and specify the css style in the specified class.

Comment: This what i wanted thnk you, Okay in place of values should I need to specify px or any??

Comment: try changing the px values until you get the desired result. So, for example you can start with `10px`

Comment: lblTest.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-left", "<value>");
didn't work

Comment: `lblTest.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("margin-left", "10px");`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding a span from .cs file like :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Label1.Text ="<span style=\"margin: 0px 0px 0px 180px;\"></span>" + "your text";
}
```

Comment: sure I shall try it out

Comment: Sure...i have tested out

Comment: okay in my case there is a textbox beside label, in this case do label get centre align ??